# preventDefault() won't work with form.submit()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get my login form to either close my lightbox, or change the text of an errorbox depending on whether or not the login attempt was a success.  I'm not sure, but i think it has to do with my

```
 onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);"
```

which is a JS function that hashes a password, then continues the form submit.  it ends with

```
    form.submit();
```

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">       
    Email: <input class="searchform" type="text" name="email" size="20"/><br />
    Password: <input class="searchform" type="password"                         name="password" id="password" size="20"/><br />
            <input type="button"  class="searchform"
                   value="Submit" size="40"  style="height:45px; width:90px"
                    onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" /> 
           <input type="text" id="errorbox" style="height:45px; width:180px" value=""><br>
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  !(function($){
   $(function() {
         $('form[name="login_form"]').on('submit', function(event){

            event.preventDefault();//don't reload the page
            $.post('includes/process_login.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
              //data is a json object which contans the reponse
              data = $.parseJSON(data);
              $("fade").fadeOut();
              $("light").fadeOut();
            },
            function(data){//error callback
                  data = $.parseJSON(data);
              if(data.forbidden){
                  $("#errorBox").html("Error!");
              }
              else if(data.error){
                $("#errorBox").html("Invalid request!");
              }
            });
          });
          return false;
    });
})(window.jQuery);
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['p'];

      if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
          http_response_code(200);//HTTP OK, requires php 5.4
          $response['success'] = true;

    } else {
      // Login failed 
      $response['error'] = true;
      http_response_code(401);//HTTP forbidden
  }
  } else {
     // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
      $response['error'] = true;
      http_response_code(400);//HTTP bad request
   }

echo json_encode($response);
```

When I log in, the preventDefault() doesn't work.  It opens process_login.php in a new page and displays "{"success":true}"  on a blank page.  Any suggestions? (keeping in mind that it needs to be as secure as possible)

Comment: are you sure the submit event is triggered? debug with an `alert()` or an `console.log('');` i would also use an ID and not the form name.

Comment: Where is your formhash() function? If it ends with the submit action, then the form will be submitted regardless of the preventDefault on the event above.

Comment: I don't think event.preventDefault() wotks with the submit event, try with clck

Comment: @Sebweb - `preventDefault()` does work with submit assuming the handler gets called. But `form.submit()` may be bypassing the handler.

Comment: so any ideas how i can formhash AND preventDefault?

Comment: you can't use `form.submit()` with jquery submit handlers, `form.submit` doesn't raise an event to prevent.

Comment: is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving it all into a single handler call. By changing the `type="button"` to `type="submit"` on your form.

```
<form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">       
Email: <input class="searchform" type="text" name="email" size="20"/><br />
Password: <input class="searchform" type="password"                         name="password" id="password" size="20"/><br />

        <input type="submit"  class="searchform" value="Submit" size="40"  style="height:45px; width:90px"                     /> 
       <input type="text" id="errorbox" style="height:45px; width:180px" value=""><br>
```

Then you could move your formhash function into the submit function

```
!(function($){
$(function() {
     $('form[name="login_form"]').on('submit', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();//don't reload the page

        formhash(var1, var2);

        $.post('includes/process_login.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
          //data is a json object which contans the reponse
          data = $.parseJSON(data);
          $("fade").fadeOut();
          $("light").fadeOut();
        },
...//the rest of your code
```